# How to drag-and-drop data from a browser into a java swing application with a custom MIME type?

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, mime-types

I am currently writing a program that enables the user to drag-and-drop some data from a browser into a java swing application. This works as intended for the mime type "text/plain", but when using a custom mime type in the javascript, the java application does not receive the data anymore.

The javascript side is done as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61689228/11948496) answer:

```
for (const el of document.querySelectorAll('[draggable="true"]')) {
  el.addEventListener('dragstart', (e) => {
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', e.currentTarget.dataset.content);
  });
}
```

The java application looks like this MRE. The MRE just prints out any received drops.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTarget;
import java.awt.dnd.DropTargetDropEvent;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JTextArea area = new JTextArea();

        area.setDropTarget(new DropTarget() {
            @Override
            public synchronized void drop(DropTargetDropEvent dtde) {
                dtde.acceptDrop(TransferHandler.COPY_OR_MOVE);
                try {
                    // For testing
                    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dtde.getTransferable().getTransferDataFlavors()));
                    // Business logic, e.g.
                    System.out.println(dtde.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor));
                } catch (UnsupportedFlavorException | IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

        frame.add(area);
        // Only for MRE, never set size like this for actual programs
        area.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 100));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

This works as it should with the jsfiddle from the linked answer. However, the data that should be transferred is not just a plain text but actually a json string. Also, the string should only be dropped in my own application and not into any text editor. Therefore I changed the mime type in the javascript to `'text/json'`. On the java side, I replaced

```
System.out.println(dtde.getTransferable().getTransferData(DataFlavor.stringFlavor));
```

with

```
System.out.println(dtde.getTransferable().getTransferData(new DataFlavor("text/json;class=java.lang.String")));
```

Which leads to an `UnsupportedFlavorException` in that line:

```
java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException: text/json
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.dnd.SunDropTargetContextPeer.getTransferData(SunDropTargetContextPeer.java:256)
    at java.desktop/sun.awt.datatransfer.TransferableProxy.getTransferData(TransferableProxy.java:73)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.dnd.DropTargetContext$TransferableProxy.getTransferData(DropTargetContext.java:386)
    at Main$1.drop(Main.java:23)
```

Additionally, the `TransferDataFlavors` array is empty, suggesting no `DataFlavor` is available. I considered to overwrite the `FlavorMap` to ensure the native mime type is mapped to the correct flavor, but debugging the `getFlavorsForFormats` method in `DataTransferer` revealed only the following natives are requested (using chrome):
"DragContext", "chromium/x-renderer-taint", "Chromium Web Custom MIME Data Format", and "DragImageBits", so my custom mime type is not even available as native type.

How do I transfer the data correctly from the browser to the java application? Do I need to register my flavor somewhere? Or is this not possible and I need to stick to `text/plain`?

Comment: "However, the data that should be transferred is not just a plain text but actually a JSON string."  Isn't JSON plain text?  "Also, the string should only be dropped in my own application and not into any text editor."  You have no control over how other applications process data,

Comment: True, but I hope by using a non-standard mime type at least normal programs will not attempt to parse it. I want to prevent the user dropping into like notpad and thereby pasting the json, since that makes little sense. Thats the downside of the described working solution I want to avoid.

Comment: Upon copy or cut, convert the JSON string to one of the defined mime types.  Your process would then convert it back to a String.